# How to handle both integer and string from raw_input?

Tags: python, user-input

Still trying to understand python. It is so different than php.

I set the choice to integer, the problem is on my menu I need to use letters as well.

How can I use integer and string together?
Why can I not set to string than integer?

```
def main(): # Display the main menu
    while True:
        print
        print "  Draw a Shape"
        print "  ============"
        print
        print "  1 - Draw a triangle"
        print "  2 - Draw a square"
        print "  3 - Draw a rectangle"
        print "  4 - Draw a pentagon"
        print "  5 - Draw a hexagon"
        print "  6 - Draw an octagon"
        print "  7 - Draw a circle"
        print
        print "  D - Display what was drawn"
        print "  X - Exit"
        print

        choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ')

        if (choice == 'x') or (choice == 'X'):
            break

        elif (choice == 'd') or (choice == 'D'):
            log.show_log()

        try:
            choice = int(choice)
            if (1 <= choice <= 7):

                my_shape_num = h_m.how_many()
                if ( my_shape_num is None): 
                    continue

                # draw in the middle of screen if there is 1 shape to draw
                if (my_shape_num == 1):
                    d_s.start_point(0, 0)
                else:
                    d_s.start_point()
                #
                if choice == 1: 
                    d_s.draw_triangle(my_shape_num) 
                elif choice == 2: 
                    d_s.draw_square(my_shape_num) 
                elif choice == 3:             
                    d_s.draw_rectangle(my_shape_num) 
                elif choice == 4:             
                    d_s.draw_pentagon(my_shape_num) 
                elif choice == 5:             
                    d_s.draw_hexagon(my_shape_num) 
                elif choice == 6:             
                    d_s.draw_octagon(my_shape_num) 
                elif choice == 7: 
                    d_s.draw_circle(my_shape_num)

                d_s.t.end_fill() # shape fill color --draw_shape.py-- def start_point

            else:
                print
                print '  Number must be from 1 to 7!'
                print

        except ValueError:
            print
            print '  Try again'
            print
```

Comment: Not clear what the problem is; the menu aspect of this seems to be working fine: break gets executed when X is entered, log.show_log() is executed when D is entered, and my_shape_num gets assigned when an integer in 1..7 is entered.

Comment: the problem is: if choice is D; i get log.show_log() then I get the error message '  Try again'

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with string/int; its that your "try" should be wrapped in an "else".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer your question with another question:
**Is it really necessary to mix letters and numbers?**
**Can't they just be all strings?**

Well, let's take the long way and see what the program is doing:

1. Display the main menu
2. Ask/receive the user input

   - If is valid: ok
   - If not: print an error message and repeat
3. Now we have a valid input

   - If is a letter: do a special tasks
   - If is a number: call the right draw-function

**Point 1.** Let's make a function for this:

```
def display_menu():
    menu_text = """\
  Draw a Shape
  ============

  1 - Draw a triangle
  2 - Draw a square
  D - Display what was drawn
  X - Exit"""
    print menu_text
```

`display_menu` is very simple so there's no need to explain what it does, but we'll see later the advantage of putting this code into a separate function.

**Point 2.** This will be done with a loop:

```
options = ['1', '2', 'D', 'X']

while 1:
    choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ')
    if choice in options:
        break
    else:
        print 'Try Again!'
```

**Point 3.** Well, after a second thought maybe the special tasks are not so special, so let's put them too into a function:

```
def exit():
    """Exit"""  # this is a docstring we'll use it later
    return 0

def display_drawn():
    """Display what was drawn"""
    print 'display what was drawn'

def draw_triangle():
    """Draw a triangle"""
    print 'triangle'

def draw_square():
    """Draw a square"""
    print 'square'
```

Now let's put it all together:

```
def main():
    options = {'1': draw_triangle,
               '2': draw_square,
               'D': display_drawn,
               'X': exit}

    display_menu()
    while 1:
        choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ').upper()
        if choice in options:
            break
        else:
            print 'Try Again!'

    action = options[choice]   # here we get the right function
    action()     # here we call that function
```

The key to your switch lies in `options` that now is no more a `list` but a `dict`, so if you simply iterate on it like `if choice in options` your iteration is on the *keys*:`['1', '2', 'D', 'X']`, but if you do `options['X']` you get the exit function (isn't that wonderful!).

Now let's improve again, because maintaining the main menu message and the `options` dictionary it's not too good, a year from now I may forget to change one or the other, I will not get what I want and I'm lazy and I don't want to do twice the same thing, etc...
So why don't pass the `options` dictionary to `display_manu` and let `display_menu` do all the work using the doc-strings in `__doc__` to generate the menu:

```
def display_menu(opt):
    header = """\
  Draw a Shape
  ============

"""
    menu = '\n'.join('{} - {}'.format(k,func.__doc__) for k,func in opt.items())
    print header + menu
```

We'll need `OrderedDict` instead of `dict` for `options`, because `OrderedDict` as the name suggests keep the order of its items (take a look at the [official doc](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)). So we have:

```
def main():
    options = OrderedDict((('1', draw_triangle),
                           ('2', draw_square),
                           ('D', display_drawn),
                           ('X', exit)))

    display_menu(options)
    while 1:
        choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ').upper()
        if choice in options:
            break
        else:
            print 'Try Again!'

    action = options[choice]
    action()
```

Beware that you have to design your actions so that they all have the same signature (they should be like that anyway, they are all actions!). You may want to use callables as actions: instances of class with `__call__` implemented. Creating a base `Action` class and inherit from it will be perfect here.

Comment: Pretty thorough, but I noticed you mixed 2.x with 3.x wrt the `print` and `raw_input` statement. (That is, you used `raw_input` in a script with 3.x's `print()`.)

Comment: @Edwin: **The script works in `python 2.x`**. At the beginning there are a couple of `print()` but since there's only one string inside you wouldn't notice the difference in `python-2.x` since `('Try Again') == 'Try Again'`. It's like if the brackets were on the text instead of on the `print`. Anyway I'll fix them to clear any doubts :)

Comment: I stand corrected, then. Another instance of weird shit you learn on SO.

Comment: That's a nice touch using `OrderedDict`. Using an ordinary `dict` and sorting the keys would also work here, but `OrderedDict` is definitely better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking here. `raw_input()` always returns a `str` type. If you want to convert user input automatically to an `int` or other (simple) type you can use the `input()` function, which does this.

You have chosen to let the user enter either a letter or a number, you could equally assign the "letter" options to number in the menu. Or, you could take more advantage of the `try`/`except`, e.g.:

```
try:
    choice = int(user_input)
    if choice == 1:
        # do something
    elif ...
except ValueError: # type(user_input) != int
    if choice == 'X' or choice == 'x':
        # do something
    elif ...
    else:
        print 'no idea what you want' # or print menu again
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code can be simplified a bit:

```
def main():
    while 1:
        print
        print "  Draw a Shape"
        print "  ============"
        print
        print "  1 - Draw a triangle"
        print "  2 - Draw a square"
        print "  3 - Draw a rectangle"
        print "  4 - Draw a pentagon"
        print "  5 - Draw a hexagon"
        print "  6 - Draw an octagon"
        print "  7 - Draw a circle"
        print
        print "  D - Display what was drawn"
        print "  X - Exit"
        print
        choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ').strip().upper()
        if choice == 'X':
            break
        elif choice == 'D':
            log.show_log()
        elif choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'):
            my_shape_num = h_m.how_many()
            if my_shape_num is None:
                continue
            elif my_shape_num == 1:
                d_s.start_point(0, 0)
            else:
                d_s.start_point()
            if choice == '1':
                d_s.draw_triangle(my_shape_num)
            elif choice == '2':
                d_s.draw_square(my_shape_num)
            elif choice == '3':
                d_s.draw_rectangle(my_shape_num)
            elif choice == '4':
                d_s.draw_pentagon(my_shape_num)
            elif choice == '5':
                d_s.draw_hexagon(my_shape_num)
            elif choice == '6':
                d_s.draw_octagon(my_shape_num)
            elif choice == '7':
                d_s.draw_circle(my_shape_num)
            d_s.t.end_fill()
        else:
            print
            print '  Invalid choice: ' + choice
            print
```

Comment: Add `.lower()` and use `choice in [str(i) for i in range(1, 7)]` and it's perfect.

Comment: @RobWouters thanks for your suggestion. I added the lower(), but I'll stick with the tuple `('1', ...)`, it's easier to understand for someone who's just learning to program

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Since the numeric input *isn't actually used for numeric operations*, just leave it as a string, so that you always have a string and proceed accordingly. Another way to simplify the check, that's still easy to understand (but less flexible!!!) is `choice in '1234567'`; `in` is special-cased for strings to do substring search.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `choice in '1234567'` is simpler but will lead to problems if, for example, the user types `23`

Answer (score 1):

> How can i use integer and string together? Why can i not set to string than integer?

Well, [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is a pretty useful thing:

```
>>> a_string = "Hi, I'm a string and I'm"
>>> an_integer = 42
>>> another_string = "milliseconds old"
>>> we_are_the_champions = "%s %d %s" % (a_string, an_integer, another_string)
>>> we_are_the_champions
"Hi, I'm a string and I'm 42 milliseconds old"
```

You even can just throw that integer into string:

```
>>> champions_are_here = "Hi, I'm a string and I'm even older, I'm %d milliseconds old" % 63
>>> champions_are_here
"Hi, I'm a string and I'm even older, I'm 63 milliseconds old"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your 'letter options' in the except block. That block is executed if the input cannot be converted to an integer, e.g. if it is a letter.

---

It is however good custom to make your `try` blocks as small as possible. So it's better to do this:

```
try:
    choice = int(choice)
except ValueError:
    choice = choice.lower() # Now you don't have to check for uppercase input
```

You can then check if the choice was an `int` with `type(choice) == int`.

Comment: The last point is bang on.  Based on the OPs submitted code there's no need to change the type from `string` to `int`.

Comment: @sgallen, I've actually removed that part after I realized he does some general stuff if the input is an integer.

Comment: The general stuff is only needed if the inputted string is one of `('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')` there's no need to go down the `try` route with `int(choice)` when you can more quickly ascertain if the `choice` belongs to the defined iterable. I'm thinking of the case where the user enters `88`, that would pass your `try` and you'd be stepping through code unnecessarily when you could have jumped straight to the `'Number must be from 1 to 7!'` line.