# Python function won't start

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm writing a python calculator, here is the code:

```
#Python Calculator

import sys;
import cmath;

def plus():
    num1 = float(input("Input the first number: "));
    num2 = float(input("Input the second number: "));
    ans = (num1 + num2);
    print(ans);
    exit();
    return;

def minus():
    num1 = float(input("Input the first number: "));
    num2 = float(input("Input the second number: "));
    ans = (num1 - num2);
    print(ans);
    exit();
    return;

def divide():
    num1 = float(input("Input the first number: "));
    num2 = float(input("Input the second number: "));
    ans = (num1 / num2);
    print(ans);
    exit();
    return;

def multiply():
    num1 = float(input("Input the first number: "));
    num2 = float(input("Input the second number: "));
    ans = (num1 * num2);
    print(ans);
    exit();
    return;

def power():
    num1 = float(input("Input the number: "));
    num2 = float(input("Input the power: "));
    ans = cmath.pow(num1, num2);
    print(ans);
    exit();
    return;

def square():
    num1 = float(input("Input the number: "));
    ans = cmath.sqrt(num1);
    print(ans);
    exit();
    return;

def inputs():
    print("Select which function you would like to use:");
    print("1 for Plus");
    print("2 for Minus");
    print("3 for Divide");
    print("4 for Multiply");
    print("5 for Power");
    print("6 for Square Root");
    func = input();

    if func == 1:
        plus();
    elif func == 2:
        minus();
    elif func == 3:
        divide();
    elif func == 4:
        multiply();
    elif func == 5:
        power();
    elif func == 6:
        square();
    return;

def exit():
    exit = str(input("Run again? y/n: "));
    if exit == "Y" or exit == "y":
        inputs();
        print ("");
    elif exit == "N" or exit == "n":
        sys.exit();
    else:
        exit();
    return;

print ("Python Calculator");
print("");
inputs();
```

Now the problem is, once you have inputted the function you want to run, the program just closes. I am relatively new to python, but not to programming. Also is anything wrong with the way this is coded (i.e. sloppy coding) please tell me.

Comment: You know that you don't need to put semicolons in the end of each string, don't you?

Comment: You also don't need to explicitly `return` at the end of every function. Returning from a function is what happens anyway when it reaches the end. Also, while calling back to `inputs()` from `exit()` will work for a while, it's messy and suggests further misunderstanding of how functions work.

Comment: Anyway, to find out what is actually going wrong with the program, you should run it from an already existing command window (that won't close when the program exits).

Comment: You're suffering of the same bad design of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8961627/1132524). I'm not advertising, but [mine answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8962511/1132524) there is exactly appliable here too (with obviusly python3 corrections).

Answer (score 4):

Your input is probably String (e.g. `"6"`) instead of the number `6`.

In general, I think that your code is unnecessary long, and breaks the [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. For starters, you can ask for the two numbers in a single place, and then call the relevant function to perform the relevant operation.

A more concise design would use Python operators:

```
funcs=[operator.add, operator.sub, operator.div, 
       operator.mul, operator.pow, your_square_function]
```

You can ask for the function type, then call the relevant function (see Lev's answer).

There interesting case is `sqr`, which takes a single argument, instead if two. This can be solved by specifying the number of arguments each function takes:

```
funcs=[(operator.add, 1), (operator.sub, 2), (operator.div, 2),
       (operator.mul, 2), (operator.pow, 2), (your_square_function, 1)]
```

The solution is now simple - ask for the function number, ask for the right number of arguments, and call `funcs[input_number][0]`.

This idea can be elaborated, so that the function name is also stored:

```
funcs=[("Plus", operator.add, 1),   ("Minus", operator.sub, 2), 
       ("Divide", operator.div, 2), ("Multiply", operator.mul, 2), 
       ("Power", operator.pow, 2),  ("Square root", your_square_function, 1)]
```

Now you program should look like (pseudocode):

```
 for f in funcs:
      print id, function_name
 ask for id
 ask for relevant number of arguments
 run funcs[id] with relevant number of arguments
```

Comment: Thank you very much, python was inputting the "func" variable as a string, so that has fixed the program, now I need to work on a better design as you suggested. Again, Thank You!

Comment: You've picked the right language - you'll be surprised how short and readable your code will be.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam notes, the problem is that you don't convert `func` to `int`.
Since you also ask for advice about the code organization, I can suggest the following to get rid of the stacked `elif` clauses:

```
functions = [plus, minus, divide, multiply, power, square]
try:
    func = int(input())
    functions[func-1]()
except:
    print("Please choose an existing function number.")
    exit()
```

Comment: This can be expanded to operators - see my answer.

Comment: I'd be cautious about advising a python new comer to use an `except all`.

Comment: @MattH Would you write `except (ValueError, IndexError)` there?

Comment: The "ideal" way would be to catch `ValueError` and reply "Please enter a number" then `IndexError` with "Please enter a number from 1 to %s".

Comment: Or explicitly check if your list contains such index.